# Manually set models.DateTimeField

Tags: python, django

I've created a Transaction table which I want to test, one of the most important field of this table is:

```
models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
```

In order to test my app with the database, I need historical data. Currently when I create a transaction, it sets the date and time automatically, so it is always current.

I need previous month data and I'm wondering if I can manually set the above field when I create a transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Currently when I create a transaction, it sets the date and time automatically

You can always override that default value before you save the model instance, for the example below let's assume your `DateTimeField` with the default value is called `timestamp`:

```
import datetime

transaction = Transaction()
transaction.timestamp = timestamp # Overrides the default
                                  # You can use a datetime.datetime 
                                  # instance as value
# transaction.timestamp = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
transaction.save()
```

"Override" is a big word, since the default is only used when you don't provide a value.

> and what is the format of the timestamp? is it timestamp = datetime (year, month, day, hour..)?

Yes the `DateTimeField` field will accept a [`datetime.datetime` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects).

Comment: and what is the format of the timestamp? is it timestamp = datetime (year, month, day, hour..)? Thanks .

Comment: Yes, added that to the answer

Comment: Thanks! I did datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 2) and it worked.